# test login with karma failed, got error of unexpected request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

I got error of using karma testing my auth endpoint

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET partials/dashboard.html
    No more request expected
```

My spec.js

```
describe('LogController', function() {
  var $scope, controller, $location, $window;

  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$location_, _$window_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $window = _$window_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $location = _$location_;
    controller = $controller('loginCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      $location: $location,
      $window: $window
    });
  }))

   it('should log in a user and redirect to homepage', function() {

     $httpBackend.whenPOST('/user/login').respond(200);
     $scope.username = 'test';
     $scope.password = '123456';
     $scope.login();

     $httpBackend.flush();
     $scope.$digest();
     expect($location.path()).toBe('/x'); 
   });

})
```

I thought I already flush()? why it call my partial/dashboard.html? I'm lost.

Comment: Try using `$scope.$apply();` instead of `$scope.$digest();`

Comment: @TomePejoski no different

Comment: Can you also add your code to the question.

Comment: @TomePejoski http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103179/how-do-i-stub-window-localstorage-in-my-angularjs-unit-tests?noredirect=1#comment69410449_41103179 I found my answer, just whitelist the partial template but now I got another issue.