# How do I stub `$window.localStorage` in my AngularJS unit tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $window, $auth) {
    $scope.login = function() {
      $auth.login($scope.user)
        .then(function(response) {
          if(response.data.users.status === 'success'){
            $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.username;
            $window.localStorage.user = JSON.stringify(response.data.users);
            $location.path('/');
          }
        }).catch(function(response){
          if(response.data.users.status === 'error'){
            $scope.error = response.data.users.error;
          }
        })
    };
  });
```

I get the error:

> ```
> users is undefined error
> ```

when testing above code with Karma and Jasmine.

The spec is below:

```
describe('LogController', function() {

  var $scope, controller, $location, $window;

  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$location_ , _$window_ , _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $window = _$window_
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $location = _$location_;
    controller = $controller('loginCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      $location: $location,
      $window: $window
    });
  }))

   it('should log in a user and redirect to homepage', function() {

     $httpBackend.when('POST','/user/auth').respond(200);

     //whitelist all view
     $httpBackend.whenGET(/partials.*/).respond(200, '');
     $scope.username = 'test'; 
     $scope.password = '123456';
     $scope.login();

     $httpBackend.flush();
     $scope.$apply();
     expect($location.path()).toBe('/x'); 
   });

})
```

What is `users` undefined? And how do I mock out a response from `$window.localStorage` so it won't be?

Comment: The error, the code, and the expected result need to be in your question as well. You can't use a Pastebin to post information we need to see.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thank you sir, but do u have an answer for this? I'm stuck for hours.

Comment: Your issue is that you need to include a `data` object for your mocked response, currently you're returning an empty string:  ` $httpBackend.whenGET(/partials.*/).respond(200, '');`. That empty string should be a data object: `{data: { "users": { "status" : "Worked"} } }`

Comment: How do I write expect in this case? Can you post an answer sir?

Comment: I tried your answer I got the same error still.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker sir

Answer (score 0):

Youshould mock the response for login
 `$httpBackend.when('POST','/user/auth').respond(200, mockResponseData);`

where:

`mockResponseData = {
      "data": {
          "username": "someValue",
          "users": {
             "status": "success"
          }
      }
  }`